# Trying to show a projection from $Im T$ along $Ker T$ given that $T^2=T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $ T^2=T$, I have already proved that there exists a vector space $V=\operatorname{Im}P \oplus \operatorname{Ker}P$. I am having trouble proving that T is a projection onto $Im T$ along $Ker T$ . I tried the following:

$$T(T(ImT+KerT))=T(ImT+KerT)$$
$$\Rightarrow T(T(ImT+KerT))=T(ImT)$$
$$\Rightarrow T(ImT+KerT)=ImT$$

I feel like I am only allowed to do this if T is injective though. Any hints?

Comment: $T$ projects onto $\operatorname{im}T$, not $\ker T$.

Comment: Oops. That's what I meant.

Comment: Let $x\in \operatorname{im} T$. Then $x = Ty$ for some $y$. Therefore $Tx =\,?$

Comment: It would not even suffice to show  what you want to show. You need that the map is identity of im T, not just that it leaves im T invariant.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $V=\operatorname{im}T\oplus\ker T$, which means two checks:

1. $\operatorname{im}T\cap\ker T=\{0\}$
2. $V=\operatorname{im}T+\ker T$

Proofs.

1. Suppose $v\in\operatorname{im}T\cap\ker T$; then $v=Tx$ for some $x$ and so $Tv=T^2x=Tx=v$. As $v\in\ker T$, we get $v=Tv=0$.
2. Let $v\in V$. Then $v=Tv+(v-Tv)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes. I know how to prove that V is a direct sum. I'm just having trouble proving the projection.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't understand where's the problem

Comment: How do I prove that $T(ImT+KerT)=ImT$

Comment: @Jonathan Isn't it obvious? Use $\operatorname{im}T+\ker T=V$ and $T(V)=\operatorname{im}T$ by definition..

Comment: Oh yeah that's right. Thank you.

Comment: is $Tv$ is a different way to write $T(v)$? or is it 2 different things?

Comment: @Jneven Just the same